# Is it bad If I use the ServiceProvider interface to resolve my properties in .NET Core for Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

Is it bad If I use the ServiceProvider interface to resolve my properties in .NET Core for Dependency Injection

let say I have the following

```
    private readonly IRecipeRepository _recipeRepository;
    private readonly IMediaResource _resourceUpload;
    private readonly IAWSMedia _awsMedia;
```

and then do this

```
    public RecipeService(IServiceProvider service)
    {
        _recipeRepository = service.GetService<IRecipeRepository>();
        _resourceUpload = service.GetService<IMediaResource>();
        _awsMedia = service.GetService<IAWSMedia>();
    }
```

instead of this

```
    public RecipeService(IRecipeRepository recipeRepo, IMediaResource media, IAWSMedia awsMedia )
    {
        _recipeRepository = recipeRepo;
        _resourceUpload = media;
        _awsMedia = awsMedia ;
    }
```

Comment: Think about the consequences for unit testing...

Comment: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

Comment: @ta.speot.is +1
If you have to inject many dependencies and you have to do it in multiple places, you may consider using aggregate services.

Comment: In this case, I would argue that it is *not* primarily opinion-based, since the demonstrated code sample is a well-known and well-documented anti-pattern called Service Locator, as @KirkLarkin correctly references. Rather, this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first bit of code is called the service locator *anti*-pattern, as in something you should *not* do. However, the answer to your question depends on context you have not provided.

In the majority of cases, no, you should not just inject `IServiceProvider`. However, in some scenarios, you have no choice but to: namely with things in singleton scope. If you have a singleton-type class, an `IHostedService` implementation, etc., you cannot inject anything but other singleton-scoped services. If you need something in a different scope like a `DbContext`, then you can only get that by injecting `IServiceProvider` and creating a scope:

```
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var foo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Foo>();
    // do something with foo;
}
```

However, remember that the instance retrieved is tied to the scope. In other words, when the `using` statement closes, it will be disposed. Therefore, you need to do any work with that instance *inside* that scope. You cannot do something like set an instance variable on your class, and the attempt to use it later, as you'll then get an `ObjectDisposedException`.